# C# Prism: Instantiate Model before View Instantiation

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, mef

TL;DR Is there a way to force **MEF** Prism container to instantiate a class before it's instantiated by View Disovery? i.e before `regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion`

I have a business process whereby the user logs in, and then I kick off some database reads.  The `LoginEvent` is registered to the `EventAggregator` so that other parts of the application can hear it.  The problem is that my model `MyModel` is only instantiated after the dependent views have been registered which of course happens **after** the login event has passed and gone. I could do this `MyModel`'s constructor but that feels sloppy.

Current Process

```
1. User logs in
2. LoginEvent is dispatched
2. View switches to MyView
3. MyModel is instantiated and listens for LoginEvent that will never be dispatched
```

Desired Process

```
1. MyModel is instantiated and listens for LoginEvent
2. User Logs in
3. LoginEvent is dispatched
4. MyModel hears LoginEvent and kicks of data read.
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using Prism module concepts, then you can activate/instantiate your view ahead of time and then register with the region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate your view ahead of time so that it is available to listen on events. You can use [Module concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405479(v=pandp.40).aspx) as described in prism docs to instantiate your view inside your module Initialize event. This will have following sequence:

1. App starts up
2. Module starts up
3. View instantiated & registered
4. User Logs in
5. LoginEvent intercepted
6. View switches

Following example gives you some outline (hasn't been tested, but should be structurally valid):

```
public class ModuleInit : IModule
{
  .....
  CompositionContainer container;
  IRegionManager regionManager;

  [ImportingConstructor]
  public ModuleInit(CompositionContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
  {
      this.container = container;
      this.regionManager = regionManager;
  }

  public void Initialize()
  {
     var myView = this.container.GetExportedValue<MyView>();
     regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("myregion", () => myView);
  }
}
```